# identifier "cout" is undefinedC/C++(20)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In C++, I am receiving red squiggly lines under cout, endl, vectors, etc. even though I run the code there is no error=. I am using Studio Code and using C++ Extension Pack. This has only become an issue as of last week for some unknown reason, nothing has been changed within the settings.

[image]
Now it's not showing legit errors and I can't find a solution to fix it.

Comment: Please read [why you should not upload images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Please don't post images of code. How have you configured intellisense?

Comment: ***I am using Studio Code and using C++ Extension Pack*** Did you follow the instructions for your compiler / OS? If you are on MS Windows did you install msys2 and use that to install MinGW?  I ask this because many new people don't follow the official instructions and have a lot of problems because of that. The official instructions are here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: Yes I have installed msys2 and have checked the installation in the command prompt.

Comment: @AlanBirtles it's not that easy to show IDE complaints, rather than compiler errors.

Comment: I just tried installing everything on another system and am getting the same issue.

Comment: I just tested and it worked without any problem for me on Win11 VSCode with msys2: [https://ibb.co/m0VvQNX](https://ibb.co/m0VvQNX)

Comment: Fixed it by uninstalling absolutely everything and reinstalling Studio Code and Mysis. Whatever was causing this annoying bug, I will never know.

Comment: In the case of inexplicable compiler errors or red squiggles in VS Code, you should add the tasks.json and c_cpp_preferences.json files to the question. The problem is almost always in at least one of them.